# Mongo - Searching for documents that don't match a particular value format?

Tags: mongodb

So I have a key called `text` that is supposed to be like the following:

```
"text" : "This is the actual text. It's supposed to a string of sentences just like this example."
```

However, due to incorrect data, I sometimes have things that are in the wrong formats. Is it possible to query for certain value formats in Mongo? I.e

```
"text" = ["It's an element in the array, this is wrong"]
```

Is it possible to query for a particular value structure with `find()`? Or rather all documents that don't match a certain format? Just new to mongo, and I'm not sure if this is possible.

Comment: Are you saying that "in error" some of that data is instead stored as an "array" as a single element as opposed to being just a "string"? So now you want to find all the data that actually used an "array" for this field?

Comment: @NeilLunn Basically, I want to find all documents for which this field isn't a string as a data cleaning step, if that makes sense

Comment: @NeilLunn Thanks for the link! However my question isn't just asking to look for things like `["one erroneous format"]`. I have no idea what the wrong format might be. Is there a way to match everything but a certain type, i.e `"the correct format"`?

Comment: Yes it is. Your question is an exact duplicate. You are *"looking for things in an array"*. Just because you call it "the correct format" does not change the essential question you are asking. In fact if you actually knew what you were asking you should have found the answer yourself. Instead I clarified with you what you were asking and pointed you at the existing answer.